# EBX custom error message using Tablet Tigger in java class

Tags: java, spring, java-8, tibco-business-works

could you please suggest me any way to set custom error message in EBX java class which extend TableTrriger

```
public class ExampleTrigger extends TableTrigger{

    @Override
    public void setup(TriggerSetupContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAfterCreate(AfterCreateOccurrenceContext aContext) throws OperationException {
        int id = aContext.getOccureContext.get_Int(Path.Student.Root_STUDET_ID);
        int number=18;
        if(id==number){
           // here i want to set error message that will show on UI
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to print error messeage:

```
System.err.println("Error messeage here");
```

Comment: add need to show error message on EBX UI not in console

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved it. If not, try this.

```
throw OperationException.createError("messa Error");
```